# android: html marquee in web-view

Tags: android

i want to display text in htlm marquee fashion...
what should i write in android XML and code?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i tried all the code but the best way i got that i show you, so that you can get good result for the webview.

```
WebView mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

String summary = "<html><body><MARQUEE>"+tiker+"</MARQUEE></body></html>";

mWebView.loadData(summary, "text/html", "utf-8");
```

thanks... for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your XML for the TextView your using.

```
android:singleLine="true" 
android:ellipsize="marquee"
android:marqueeRepeatLimit ="marquee_forever"
android:scrollHorizontally="true"
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

Comment: i applied it bt it don't work. actully i want to display stock information as marquee in android... but the string which i get from server, it not working marquee effect and just display text... what will i do?

Comment: As an experience TextView marquee is so buggy